# my code stops working after certain changes

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I was trying to reload the page after the success  of  xhr.send(data);

but I think that failed

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "User/adde", true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (xhr.status==403 || xhr.status==404) {

           alert("ERROR LOADING 3-UPLOAD.PHP");
         } else {
           //alert(this.response);
         }
    };

    xhr.send(data); // the data will send from here.

    success: function(data){
      if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)

        setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)

           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)

        }, 5000); 
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a look at this documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload